# How to fix the error: Exception thrown : read access violation?

Tags: c++

Im trying to send DATA from my arduino to my visual studio c++ program. But after my program on visual studio recives the data it crashes and I get the error code:

> "Exception thrown: read access violation. _Ptr_user was 0x7."

Can you guys help me?

I have the following code:

```
while (video.read(frame))
    {
        cv::imshow("videofeed", frame);
        cv::Mat frame2;

        std::string test;
        char* sensor = const_cast<char*>(test.c_str()); 
        arduino.readSerialPort(sensor, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

        int b = *sensor;

        if (b > 0) {
            cout << b;
            Sleep(1000);
        }

        if (waitKey(30) == 'c') {
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line crashes?

Comment: int b = *sensor

Comment: Whatever sensor contains is being used as an address. Your O/S won't let you read from that address. Check the value returned by test.c_str() and verify you can read from that address. I'm guessing there's no device at that address to read from because test is an empty string..

Comment: needing to resort to `const_cast` is usually indicative that you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need some space to write into – you have none – and writing through a pointer acquired from `c_str()` has undefined behaviour.

`test` is an empty string, but you apparently want it to have `MAX_DATA_LENGTH` characters.

```
std::string test(MAX_DATA_LENGTH, '\0');
```

You also should not use `const_cast<char*>(test.c_str())`.

Use either

```
char* sensor = &test[0];
```

or

```
char* sensor = test.data();
```

You could also use `std::vector<uint8_t>`, since it looks like you're sending arbitrary data rather than strings.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> test(MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
arduino.readSerialPort(test.data(), MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
int b = test[0];
```